# how do you determine z1 and z2 and bias values in deep learning

Tags: neural-network, xor, deep-learning

[image]There is this question:

Which of the the following neural networks can represent the following function? Select all that apply.

```
(x1 AND x2) OR (NOT x1 AND NOT x2)
```

x1 and x2 and bias to z1 and z2 are given some values. Can somebody please explain, how would I calculate the layer 2 z1, z2 and bias values based on the this formula ((x1 AND x2) OR (NOT x1 AND NOT x2))

I've tried z1=g(x1+x2+b) and z2=g(x1+x2+b), then what would I do next?

Comment: The possible solutions should have weights (right now you have the same equation for z1, z2).  Then the equations should be z1=sign(wa1*x1+wa2*x2+ba1), z2=sign(wa2*x1+wa2*x2+ba2), y=sign(wb1*z1+wb2*z2+bb1)

Comment: @Peter, there are different values for x1 and x2. Z1 and z2 are shown to be both 1. How do I calculate the bias in the hidden layer. If for example in first layer bias for z1 is -1.5 and for z2 is 0.5?

Comment: @Peter, I get the formulas that you've put here. How do you calculate the weight in hidden layer?

Comment: @Peter, I attached the image to the question with possible answers. I am puzzled on calculating the bias in the hidden layer.

Comment: The bias is given.  It's the number connecting the "1" input to each unit of the next layer.  (A bias is the same as a weight from an input whose activation is always 1)

Comment: You don't calculate weights/biases.  Those are given by the numbers on the diagram.  You calculate activations (z, y), given the inputs (x) and the weights/biases (wa, wb, ba, bb)

Comment: @Peter, do you see the image I attached. The bias to z1 and z2 different. How is the biaz in middle layer (hidden layer) calculated. I'm trying to understand that part.

Comment: @Peter, since z1 and z2 are the same accross the boards, would you say all of these diagrams are correct?

Comment: Take figure 1.  The bias to z1 is -0.5.  The bias to z2 is 1.5.  The values of z1, z2 are given in the equations I gave earlier, with ba1=-0.5, ba2=1.5

Comment: *With corrected typo and better names: z1=sign(wz11*x1+wz21*x2+bz1), z2=sign(wz21*x1+wz22*x2+bz2), y=sign(wy11*z1+wy21*z2+by1)

Comment: @Peter, I follow your input. However, I do see the weight for the bias to be different in each sections which ones are correct, I am struggling to answer that part.

Comment: The correct images are the ones for which, when you plug in those values for the weights, biases, the network computes the same result as the function `(x1 AND x2) OR (NOT x1 AND NOT x2)`

Comment: @Peter, I am sorry for all these questions. I am trying to understand this without any success. I do get the z1 and z2 and y formulas. Then what, do we check what would be z1 and z2 based on truth table? It would be really helpful, if you could run through the problem?

Comment: You want to find y for each input x.  x has 4 possible values: (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1).  For each network, for each possible value of x, compute (z1, z2), which will be (0, 0), (0, 1), (1,0), or (1,1) and then compute y from z1, z2.  Y will be 0 or 1.  Then you get a truth table for each network, and you can compare this to the XOR function given.

Comment: @peter, for the first diagram, z1=(0 1 0 0), z2=(1 1 1 1), based on the truth table, Y becomes (1 1 1 1). When I look at the original function z1 OR Z2, the results become (1 1 1 1), this value is the same as y so that means this diagram is accurate. Is this how you check if the diagrams accurate?

Comment: Why are you doing z1 OR z2 ?  The original function is on x.  f(x) = (x1 AND x2) OR (NOT x1 AND NOT x2).  Over the possible x-inputs: (0,0), (0,1),(1,0),(1,1) you should get 1,0,0,1.  If your network doesn't output the same value of y for each of those inputs, then it doesn't match the function.

Comment: @Peter, Thank you so much. I think I got it. given the values from (00,01,10,11) I calculate z1 and z2 then y. I compare y to the function which is (1, 0, 0, 1). I found that b,d,e option to be equal to (1 0 01).

Comment: @Peter, can you pose one of the entry as answer, I'll accept it. Sorry for all these questions but I think it was worth it.

Comment: You should create an answer that would have helped clear up your initial confusion fastest and accept that.

Comment: I thought I'd mention a really good reference on the XOR problem (in your case: XOR complement problem) in the context of feed-forwards neural networks: http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/research/publications/techreps/pdf/TR148.pdf

Comment: @Peter, I may have sounded too quick. I went though all of the graphs and determined that 2,4,5 diagrams to be aligned with the function. However, they are not seem to be the right anser. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. First I came up with z1 and z2 equations, given (0 0,0 1, 1 0, 1 1), calculdate the y values for each diagram.
2. Then I calculated the output of this function (x1 AND x2) OR (NOT x1 AND NOT x2) for (0 0,0 1,1 0, 1 1)
3. I compare the item 2's results to the y values in item 1, which ever were the same, those are the correct choices.